# Angular-V17-SSR-Dynamic require of "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic" is not supported

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, angular-standalone-components, angular17, angular-ssr

I have recently upgraded Angular version to 17. I have updated all the dependencies for @ckeditor but still facing this issue.

Error is

```
central-error-handler.ts:5 Error: Dynamic require of "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic" is not supported
    at :4200/chunk-2JE2TMEM.js:30:9 [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/new _FormsComponent (http://localhost:4200/chunk-M44TTMSQ.js:5066:29) [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/NodeInjectorFactory.FormsComponent_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:4200/chunk-M44TTMSQ.js:7385:12) [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/getNodeInjectable (http://localhost:4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-F5XGSELL.js?v=fc281b02:2738:38) [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/createRootComponent (http://localhost:4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-F5XGSELL.js?v=fc281b02:9807:31) [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-F5XGSELL.js?v=fc281b02:9704:19) [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/ViewContainerRef2.createComponent (http://localhost:4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-F5XGSELL.js?v=fc281b02:11878:43) [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/_RouterOutlet.activateWith (http://localhost:4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-FWZNWQZB.js?v=fc281b02:1739:31) [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-FWZNWQZB.js?v=fc281b02:2229:28) [angular]
    at :4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-FWZNWQZB.js?v=fc281b02:2191:12 [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/Array.forEach (<anonymous>) [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-FWZNWQZB.js?v=fc281b02:2190:25) [angular]
    at :4200/post/adTypes/ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-FWZNWQZB.js?v=fc281b02:2207:14) [angular]
    at :4200/@fs/angular/.angular/cache/17.0.8/vite/deps/chunk-FWZNWQZB.js?v=fc281b02:2191:12 [angular]
```

Need help to resolve this issue.